# Cookie sent from backend API (nodeJS express) to forntend (NextJS) is not being set in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cookies, next.js

I have a NextJS app running on localhost:3000 and a node express API running on localhost:3030. After a request is sent from the frontend to the backend login route, am setting a cookie in the frontend from the backend api called refresh_token, when I inspect the request I can see the cookie in the network inspector but its never been set in the frontend. Please how do I fix this?

[image: request from the inspector]

[image: still no cookie being set]

axios instance

```js
const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3030',
});
export default instance;
```

frontend code

```
axios.post('/login', values, { withCredentials: true })
    .then((res) => {
        console.log('Response', res);
        console.log('Response Headers', res.headers);                
        setAuthorizationToken(res.data.data.tokens.accessToken);
        setSubmitting(false);
        router.push('/');
})
.catch((err) => {
        setSubmitting(false);
        setError(err.response ? 
            err.response.data.error.message : err.message
        );
})
```

Comment: Please help to share code to get more info

Comment: ok I will do that

Comment: Can you run the request again, but check the headers tab this time? Does it tell you the error (should have an icon) next to the Set-Cookie response header?

Comment: @Calvin thanks that was a very helpful tip, I was able to identify the issue with that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I actually figure out the issue with @Calvin tip I was to inspect the cookie and see what wrong with it. Turns out I shouldn't set the domain on the cookie and it works.

bugged code

```js
res.cookie('refresh_token', 
{ refreshToken }, {
    httpOnly: true,
    domain: 'localhost:3000',
    signed: true,
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
});
```

fix

```js
res.cookie('refresh_token', 
{ refreshToken }, 
{
    httpOnly: true,
    signed: true,
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
});
```

Comment: Did not work for me